# URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs) in applicationContext.xml

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I created an application Context.xml at the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.
and I have added the `<!DOCTYPE>` in the xml. I am getting the below error:

> URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

You can see the snapshot below:

[image]

The xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">  // -> there comes the issue
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

Comment: Dont forget to enable **spring** plugins

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can easy solve it by: Fetch external resource.

[image]

Click the light(your is red) -> Fetch external resource.

Comment: I try this but I got No XML at the location: http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets among others. Would you know why?

Comment: Error while fetching http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Comment: This might not work as of android studio 4.1.2 (2021), I got the same error as  @NoorHossain My solution was to `Build > Clean project`

Comment: IDE has thrown "couldnt fetch "

Comment: Same here, IDE says "couldn't fetch", not sure if it's because I'm using `spring-webmvc`

Comment: No XML at the specified location: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j

Comment: I have already checked but even after that, this problem is coming.

Answer (score 37):

This did the work:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> -> Fetch external resource

Answer (score 17):

If you select and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> i.e. `More Actions...` then the following options would be displayed:

1. **Add xsi schema location for external resource**
2. **Fetch external resource** `(my preferred way)`
3. **Ignore external resource**
4. **Manually setup external resource**

Most of the time you would either select option no. 2 or 3 to get rid of this error.

Comment: May I know if is it safe to just using option 3 "Ignore external resource"?

Comment: If option 2 does not work then that might be OK I think.

Comment: When "2" is selected it opens a Map External Resource.  Clicking OK retools the warning to say: "Resource registered by this uri is not recognized."

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming this is in IntelliJ IDEA or some other JetBrains tool.  If you place  the cursor over the URL (or select it), you should see a red bulb on the left border of the window.  That red bulb, when clicked, will give you some options to correct any errors.  One of the options should be to download the DTD (Fetch external resource).  Do that and the error should go away.

Comment: No XML at the specified location: jakarta.apache.org/log4j

Answer (score 7):

For me **Build > Clean Project** worked.

Answer (score 3):

Times change and Apache simply does not support that 1.xx version of log4j anymore. That XML really is not there on that address.

***`log4j` is dead.  Long live `log4j2`!***
Look here: 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html.

New configuration language is shorter and more convenient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info"/>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you feel you must use the old version, you should download the old XML that lived at the old address, put it on your server and use the new address.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a JetBrains context, and `Fetch external resource` does not work, try File -> Invalidate Caches. Equivalent to clean project in eclipse, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answers above but none worked. It ended up working fine when I used:

**FIle | Invalidate Caches...**

Mark everything and click **Invalidate and Restart**

It will restart IntelliJ and everything was working

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was opening XML resource files from **debug** build variant while my Android Studio had **beta** build variant selected.

I switched to the **debug** build variant (to which the XML file belonged) and voila! errors gone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved it by ignoring external resource:

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on **macos**. In the document, right click on the _unknown external resource_.  Click _Show Context Actions_.  Click the "...ignore..." action.

Answer (score 0):

If "fetch" does not help, it means You have created this xml-file as empty file with .xml extention and filled config manually. Now delete it and recreate it propperly as "Spring config" file from template.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project worked for me. go to Build then click clean project.

Answer (score 0):

I used Fetch External resource initially but the error didn't go. Then I invalidated the cache and it worked for me.

Comment: Maybe this is a question. not a any answer

Answer (score 0):

Ignore external resource, it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a totally different issue where the Maven plugin was disabled. It may not be the case for you but if you have already reached this comment, please try to

File → Settings → Plugins → Maven

and then enable it. This worked for me. Thanks.